# React Webpack add new npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

How to add a new npm package with webpack? I can't understand the main idea.

Example, let's use `npm install react-ripple-effect --save-dev` from [npm package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ripple-effect)

After that, a bunch of files appears in /node_modules/react-ripple-effect

My structure:

```
>ReactApp
>>App
>>>components
----Arctic.jsx
----ArcticForm.jsx
----ArcticMessage.jsx
----Main.jsx
----Nav.jsx
>>>styles
----app.scss
---app.jsx
>>node_modules
...
>>public
---bundle.js
---index.html
--package.json
--server.js
--webpack.config.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxx",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "xxx",
  "license": "xxx",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react-ripple-effect": "^1.0.4",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
      Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx',
      Arctic: 'app/components/Arctic.jsx',
      ArcticForm: 'app/components/ArcticForm.jsx',
      ArcticMessage: 'app/components/ArcticMessage.jsx',
      applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

app.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Main = require('Main');
var Nav = require('Nav');
var Arctic = require('Arctic');

// Load foundation
require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css')
$(document).foundation();

// App css
require('style!css!sass!applicationStyles')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Arctic}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

main.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Nav = require('Nav');

var Main = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
            {props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

module.exports = Main;
```

arctic.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ArcticForm = require('ArcticForm');
var ArcticMessage = require('ArcticMessage');

var Arctic = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      name: "polar bear!"
    };
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      name: this.props.name
    };
  },
  handleNewData: function (updates) {
    this.setState(updates);
  },
  render: function(){
    var name = this.state.name;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center">Arctic</h1>
        <ArcticForm onNewData={this.handleNewData}/>
        <ArcticMessage name={name}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Arctic;
```

ArcticForm.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

var ArcticForm = React.createClass({
  onFormSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var updates = {};
    var name = this.refs.name.value;

    if (name.length > 0) {
      this.refs.name.value = '';
      updates.name = name;
    }
    this.props.onNewData(updates);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="Name" />
          <button type="submit" className="button expanded hollow">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ArcticForm;
```

ArcticMessage.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ArcticForm = require('ArcticForm');

var ArcticMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var name = this.props.name;
    return (
      <h3 className="text-center">Hi {name}</h3>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ArcticMessage;
```

The package instructions tell me to include this, but where and how? And how to include that in webpack?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { RippleButton } from 'react-ripple-effect';

class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <RippleButton>Click On Me!</RippleButton>
    )
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

Comment: Import RippleButton into the component where you want to use it, like the code above shows you. You shouldn't need to make any change to your webpack config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import in webpack...Webpack is responsible to read your source and bundle all necessary modules.

The idea is:

1. You install a module using NPM.
2. You use inside your source code using `import <module>`
3. When bulding with webpack, it reads your source code, find that `import` and bundles it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, when adding

   "import { RippleButton } from 'react-ripple-effect';"

in app.jsx, I get the following error

   "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" which comes from /node_modules/react-ripple-effect//src/components/index.js I always get that kind of errors whatever the npm package I'm adding...

Comment: That because you are not transpiling the code. `import` is ES6 feature not implemented yet on NodeJS

Comment: Thanks, I got back to webpack's basics here : [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/user/sgslo/)

Comment: If it helps, I have a post about it ... https://medium.lucaskatayama.com/bootstraping-a-react-redux-application-5fa1f239174f